# How to save changed state of dynamic created checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a problem with saving state of checkbox which is created in modal dialog via jquery function `append()`. The problem is when you close modal and open it again that state it's rewrite with `append()` function.

There is [live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/f503t1hn/) of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that on every modal call you're rebuilding it's `.html()` with a brand new HTML string.
Instead **create an in-memory checkbox** element and append that one.

***[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/f503t1hn/4/)***

```
var $cbx = $("<input>", {
  type: "checkbox",
  value: "",
  class: "form-control checkboxpicker",
  checked: true,
  name: ""
});

$('button[data-target="#myModal"]').on('click', function(){
  $('#app').html('<div class="checkboxContainer">Checkbox: </div>');
  $('.checkboxContainer').append($cbx); // Append our in-memory checkbox!
  $cbx.checkboxpicker();
});
```

To recap, whatever happens to the `$cbx` `checked` state, will always be remembered internally inside the `$cbx`. Re-appending that item - you'll always get it's last (*current*) state.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$('.checkboxpicker').prop('checked',active);` and initialize `active` as `false/true` initially.

```js
var active = false;
$('button[data-target="#myModal"]').on('click', function() {
  $('#app').html('<div class="checkboxContainer">Checkbox: </div>');
  $('.checkboxContainer').append(
    '<input class="checkboxpicker" name="" value="" type="checkbox" class="form-control">'
  );
  $('.checkboxpicker').prop('checked', active);
  $('.checkboxpicker').checkboxpicker(false);
});

$(document).on('change', '.checkboxpicker', function() {
  active = this.checked;
  console.log(active);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-checkbox/1.4.0/bootstrap-checkbox.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="app">

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### [**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/f503t1hn/5/)

Comment: I will not mind downvotes. But care to give valid reason!

Comment: @Mardzis humm.... I don't think this will work cause it replicates the issue you already have, just the inverse way.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, Not sure how this will fail..Correct me if I am wrong..Thank you :)